# How to change the getPrice() function to all Entire website

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, product-prices

Actually, We have implement some custom calculation for all type of products,

Now i have edit the 
**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php** , Its working on homepage and cart and checkoutpage., but cant change in the search page which means **www.magentosite.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=search+product+**. How can change in product search list page. please anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found, the path

1. app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Item\Abstract.php - function getPrice()
2. app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Helper\Data.php - function getPrice($product, $price.....)
3. app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php - function getPrice($product)**

These All the files need to customize the price of the product

Answer (score 0):

Products in search and layer filtered navigation use the price index for displaying. As such you must reindex "Product prices" index.

Comment: everything was reindexed... anyother way to fix this